# Which website do i have to unblock to be able to download ubuntu packages?

Tags: apt, packaging

I have a white list filter on my internet. I cannot download anything. What is the url that i should unblock to be able to enjoy the programs?

Comment: Forgot the canonical address in my answer, just added it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to white-list (if you are set it to use the main server):

```
http://ubuntu.com
https://ubuntu.com
```

and if you plan on using the canonical repository as well those:

```
http://canonical.com
https://canonical.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to figure it out. im really new t this whole thingy...